# Can we mention datatypes rather than typename and class keyword in function template definitions?

Tags: c++

Can we mention datatypes rather than just `typename` and `class` keywords inside the angular brackets?

```
template <typename var, int m> // why not generate the error here itself
void c(var x){
   int i = 2;
}

template void c<int, int> (int); // error: no match for any template declaration
```

Why do not the compiler generate error at the function template definition, when I dont use `typename or class`

I guess the error must not be generated because the typenames are matched, var is of int and m is already defined int. The error must be possible only if compiler ignores `<int m>` in the definition. but when it ignores, why not simply generate the error like `not a valid code` Could anyone explain me Is this compiler issue or any other reason

Comment: There's no error in the template declaration. Template parameters don't have to be types. They can be values, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a template with one "type" parameter and one "value" parameter. This is perfectly correct, but to use it you have to give a type and a value (which is of type int), like so: `c<AnyType,5>(...);`

Look for example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

An example of such thing is std::array<> from STL (in C++11) - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: can you clarify one more thing, are value parameters are const types ?

Comment: @user3205479 - I'm not sure I understand your question. For value parameters you can only use compile time constants - for example you cannot use a value of variable or a result of a function call. But you can use "static const" values (sometimes), constexpr values and constexpr functions. See chapter "Template non-type arguments" in the link above. EDIT: and this value is not a variable, it behaves as a class-scope or function-scope "static const" object.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's valid - read about [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). What's not valid is the explicit instantiation - the second argument needs to be a value, not a type. E.g.:

```
template void c<int, 42> (int);
```

Comment: is 'm' a const variable type? m = 45; generates error.